# Create an image popup from an iOS tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I am wanting to create a popup image like the Twitter iOS app, where you click on an image in a table view and then it fullscreens the image so you can see it better.

I tried the following:

```
         UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];  //this is called from the configurecell function
```

then the function I call is:

```
-(void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
CGPoint tapLocation = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *tapIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
Location *location = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:tapIndexPath];
UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.PNG"];  //default.png is just the placeholder for now
UIImageView *overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlayImage];
[self.tableView addSubview:overlayImageView];
}
```

This will cause an image to pop up, but only above the cell from where the image was tapped.

EDIT:

Much thanks for the inputs. I found my issue was that the uiimageview was pinned to the top of the table view because the CGRectMake was 0,0,etc,etc (0,0, is the top left). Instead, we need to set the image view to the currently visible area like so

```
-(void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
 {
CGPoint tapLocation = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *tapIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
CGFloat distanceFromBottom = [self.tableView contentOffset].y;
UIImageView *imview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, distanceFromBottom, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
imview.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
imview.image = @"Default.PNG";
imview.tag=12345;  //give tag so we can find it and dismiss it
imview.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; //make sure image isn't stretched 
[self.view addSubview:imview];  //add the subview
self.tableView.scrollEnabled=NO; //make sure we can't scroll while image is popped out

 //now lets add a gesture recognizer to make sure we can dismiss the pop up uiimageview
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissTap:)];
 tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
 tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView=YES;
 imview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [imview addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
 }


-(void)dismissTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
[[self.view viewWithTag:12345]removeFromSuperview];
self.tableView.scrollEnabled=YES;  //re enable scrolling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PopUP Title" 
                                                message:@"This is pop up window/ Alert" 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *tempImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,50,50)];
tempImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];

[alert addSubView:tempImageView]

[alert show];
```

or you can  download from [here github](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this may be the way I end up doing it. I was hoping to figure a way that wasn't an alert view, but this might be the simplest/best way. As an aside, to make this work you probably need to resize the image.

Comment: I found the problem I was having. This worked perfectly, but it would put the expanded image at the top of the tableview (which could be out of sight if you were scrolling down. I fixed it by getting the y position we were viewing (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
-(void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
CGPoint tapLocation = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *tapIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
Location *location = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:tapIndexPath];
UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.PNG"];  //default.png is just the placeholder for now
UIImageView *overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlayImage];
overlayImageView.frame = self.view.frame; // or set it as tableview.frame...set frame as per requirement.
[self.view addSubview:overlayImageView]; /You can also add a button to bring it back also.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This still causes the initial issue, which is that the default.png image appears centered and its bottom y position is set to the center of the cell from which the image was tapped.

Comment: I didn't down vote. Sorry. Not sure why. Would upvote but haven't earned enough points yet :/

Comment: thanks for your help, I found my issue, which was the frame. have it in my edits